# How can I ensure that Undo and Redo menu items have the action string added?

Tags: cocoa, menu, undo-redo

I have undo/redo working in my app.

I set the target of the undo and redo menu actions to my app delegate to implement the actions with undoAction: and redoAction: methods. The menu items' enabled bindings are bound to canUndo and canRedo properties of my undo manager and these work as expected. I set an action name when I push to the undo stack, but never see it in the menu.

Why does my menu always say Undo or Redo, not Undo Move to Trash and Redo Move to Trash ? Does the menu item normally get updated by some magic I am bypassing? I have not used the responder chain because my app delegate is not in the responder chain, and so never sees the actions.

The undo manager is created in my app delegate.

Update: changing to use the window's undo manager makes no difference.

```
-(void)undoableRemoveItemsFromListAtIndexes:(NSIndexSet*)itemIndexes;
{
    NSArray *removedItems = [[self.listController arrangedObjects] objectsAtIndexes:itemIndexes];
    [[self.undoManager prepareWithInvocationTarget:self] undoableAddItems:removedItems toListAtIndexes:itemIndexes];
    [self removeItemsFromListAtIndexes:itemIndexes];
    [self.undoManager setActionName:@"Move to Trash"];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer turned out to be one or more of the following (from help at NSCoder night Campbell):

- Use the window's undo manager, not one that I created
- Remove the bindings I had and hook up the menu items to First Responder
- Name the methods in my app delegate undo: and redo:

Once I did all that it all magically worked.

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if the undo manager -isUndoing and swap the strings appropriately.

```
NSUndoManager * um = [self undoManager];
// ...
[um setActionName:([um isUndoing]) ? @"Remove Foo" : @"Add Foo"];
```

It's important to remember a redo is an undo pushed to the redo stack.

Comment: This would solve a problem I am not having: that of the wrong menu strings. I don't get my action string at all.

Comment: Ah. I see. Sorry for not reading more carefully. Does your -undoableRemoveItemsFromListAtIndexes: method get wrapped by any other undo-related methods, causing an undo group?

Comment: Nope. I don't create any groups explicitly, and the call you see is the only one in the runloop.

Comment: "It's important to remember a redo is an undo pushed to the redo stack." ... are you sure? For example: I change the color of an object from red to yellow. Undo will be "change to red". Redo will be "change to yellow". So, I don't see how can that be the same.

Comment: Conceptually, yes (if you're doing it right). It's how it's always worked and all my apps follow this pattern (as do Apple's examples). Calling an undoable "change color" method would do a "Change to RED" which should automatically register "Change to CURRENTCOLOR" as its inverse. If the inverse is called, "Change to CURRENTCOLOR" (with RED) as the color is registered as ITS inverse. Read the documentation. It's all there. Conceptualizing and planning undo isn't as easy as it seems until you've grasped this concept thoroughly. :-)